# How To Make A Rounded Segmented Button Group On The iPhone

Tags: iphone

So I'm looking how to make a similar button group for an application on the iPhone that looks like the buttons in the Yelp About Me page or Twitter for Mobile application on the profile pages. Are these just a segmented controller? Or possibly images? I can't really find any resources for this online, so I figured I'd ask here. Let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want us to download the apps to know what it should look like?

Comment: @Eiko: the twitter buttons look like this: http://i52.tinypic.com/ftmvdi.png  The four buttons all highlight and perform actions like individual buttons or table cells. I was just wondering how this is implemented myself.

Comment: I would imagine that you could just modify the .layer property and change the border radius for that sections which is more than likely just a view of it's own.